# ORDER BY distance doesn't work with infinite scrolling

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by, distance, infinite-scroll

I have an infinite scrolling page where i want to display some adverts and order them by distance.

The $postnumbers is the initial number of adverts loaded and the $offset stands for the number of adverts loaded when scrolling down the page.

This works fine without the distance stuff. So if i just do:

```
"SELECT * FROM adverts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$postnumbers." OFFSET ".$offset.""
```

the infinite scrolling is working properly.

But if i implement the distance stuff:

```
 "SELECT *, 
    ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('$lat') ) * 
    cos( radians( lat ) ) * 
    cos( radians( lon ) - 
    radians('$lon') ) + 
    sin( radians('$lat') ) * 
    sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) 
    AS distance FROM adverts HAVING distance < '$miles' ORDER BY distance, id ASC LIMIT ".$postnumbers." OFFSET ".$offset.""
```

They are correctly ordered by distance, but only the initial adverts show up and if i scroll down nothing happens.

Does anybody have a solution or an idea that could solve my problem?

Comment: your queries aren't equivalent. first one gets a limited number of records. the other ones gets a limited number of queries that are within a certain distance. You're naturally going to get fewer records, and if there's less records than your limit allows...